# Regex matching in first two words with exclusion

Tags: regex, string, language-agnostic

I'm having some difficulty with the following requirement for a single expression. It's broken down for simplicity.

1. Match the first two words
2. With the result A, match a specific list of strings X, Y, Z
3. Unless any of A contains W

So far, the following doesn't seem to work as I would expect for requirement 1-2.

```
(?([?=^\s]+\s+[^\s]+|[^\s]+)(stringX|stringY))
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Is it actually possible?

Edit - example matches:

```
"Bob teststringX jack John"
"anotherstringY jack john"
```

Shouldn't match:

```
"Bob jack teststringY john"
"Jim teststringY John jack" (if W=Jim)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more real examples on what should match what shouldn't?

Comment: This regex uses is a C# _conditional expression_ which is unique in regex land. Is this for C# ?

Comment: Added some examples. @sln if that's the case, it wasn't intentional. It's a language agnostic question.

Comment: Can you be more specific of the labels A X,Y,Z and W. Also, this `[?=^\s]` is a character class, not an assertion.

Comment: So it looks like you want to match the strings if the last 2 words of each line match ?

Comment: @snl "([?=^\s]+\s+[^\s]+|[^\s]+)" is an attempt to grab the first two words, or one if there's only one. If thats not correct or there's a better way, I'm all for it.

Comment: @sln I want to match the given strings (X, Y, Z) only if one of them exists in the first two words. (Plus, only if neither of the first two words contain string W)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m/^\w*Jim\K|^\w+\W+\w*Jim\K|^(\w*(?:stringX|stringY)\w*)\W+(\w+)|^(\w+)\W+(\w*(?:stringX|stringY)\w*)/gm`

Let's break it down:

`m/pattern/gm`  Match **pattern** **g**lobally (find all matches), and also in **m**ultiline mode (^ and $ match the beginning and end of lines, in addition to the beginning and end of a multi-line string).

`^\w*Jim\K|var1`  Does the line begin with a word that contains **Jim**?  If so, the **\K** starts the matching over at the current place in the string.  Subsequently, the pattern won't match, since all the alternatives are anchored to the beginning of the line with **^**.  The matching is over, and you haven't captured anything.  If not, move onto var1:

`^\w+\W+\w*Jim\K|var2`  Does the second word in the line contain **Jim**?  If so, the **\K** starts the matching over at the current place in the string.  Subsequently, the pattern won't match, since all the alternatives are anchored to the beginning of the line with **^**.  The matching is over, and you haven't captured anything.  If not, move onto var2:

`^(\w*(?:stringX|stringY)\w*)\W(\w+)|var3`  Look for the beginning of a line, then 0 or more word characters (in case the first word does or doesn't begin with one of your matchstrings), then one of your matchstrings, then 0 or more word characters (in case the first word does or doesn't end with one of your matchstrings).  Then, look for a non-word character, and then 1 or more word characters.  Ignore whatever else might come next in the line.

If this matches, then both words are captured.  If this doesn't match, try var3:

`^(\w+)\W(\w*(?:stringX|stringY)\w*)`  Look for the beginning of a line, then 1 or more word characters, then a non-word character, then 0 or more word characters, then one of your matchstrings, then 0 or more word characters.

If this matches, then both words are captured.  If this doesn't match, then the line does not meet your conditions.

**Note**, though, that if your intention is just to capture the substrings of the first two words which match one of your matchstrings, rather than the whole word containing it, you can move the capturing parentheses inside the preceding and succeeding `\w*`s

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for the effort! You saved my day, just didn't expect it to be so complicated.